# RandomizedSearch or GridSearch are possible for a bagging model with weka base estimator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, weka, grid-search

with the sklearn-weka-plugin, exist any way to use RandomizedSearchCV or GridSearch (from sklearn) for a good combination of params on a Bagging Model with ADTrees as Base Estimator?

something like that:

```py
Base_CostS= WekaEstimator(classifier = base_model_1, classname="weka.classifiers.meta.CostSensitiveClassifier", 
                            options =["-cost-matrix", "[0.0 1.0; 1.0 0.0]", "-S", "1", "-W", "weka.classifiers.trees.ADTree"],
                            nominal_input_vars=[2,3,4], # which attributes need to be treated as nominal
                            nominal_output_var=True)    # class is nominal as well

bagging_model = BaggingClassifier(base_estimator = Base_CostS, n_estimators = 100, n_jobs = None, random_state = 1)

param_distributions_BG = {
    'n_estimators': [10, 50, 75, 100],
    'max_samples'   : [0.2, 0.5, 1.0],
    'bootstrap'   : [True, False],
    'base__iterations' : [10,15,20],
    'base__Expand_Nodes' : ["-3", "-2", "-1", "1"]

    
}

grid_r = RandomizedSearchCV(
        estimator  = bagging_model,
        param_distributions = param_distributions_BG,
        n_iter     = 50,
        scoring = {'Precision':'precision_macro',
                   'Recall':'recall_macro',
                   'F1_Score':'f1_macro'},
        cv         = RepeatedKFold(n_splits = 5, n_repeats = 5), 
        verbose    = 0,
        random_state = 1,
        return_train_score = True,
        refit = refit_aux
       )

grid_r.fit(X = X_data_train, y = y_data_train)

resultados = pd.DataFrame(grid_r.cv_results_)
resultados.filter(regex = '(param.*|mean_t|std_t)').drop(columns = 'params')
```

I don't know if is possible to do something like that or I must do something different.

EDIT:

when I execute it without the base estimators params

```
param_distributions_BG = {
    'n_estimators': [10, 50, 75, 100],
    'max_samples'   : [0.2, 0.5, 1.0],
    'bootstrap'   : [True, False]
}
```

I'm getting this exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: weka.classifiers.meta.CostSensitiveClassifier: Cannot handle unary class!
    weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1045)
    weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1256)
    weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1138)
    weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1468)
    weka.classifiers.meta.CostSensitiveClassifier.buildClassifier(CostSensitiveClassifier.java:506)

    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1045)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1256)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1138)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1468)
    at weka.classifiers.meta.CostSensitiveClassifier.buildClassifier(CostSensitiveClassifier.java:506)
```

So don't know if it's possible to make randomizedSearch o gridSearch on this cases that i have weka base estimators of a bagging model.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of your cross-validation splits only had a single class label (`unary`), which ADTree cannot handle.

I just pushed out release 0.0.6 of [sklearn-weka-plugin](https://pypi.org/project/sklearn-weka-plugin/) which allows you to specify the number of labels for nominal attributes (`num_nominal_input_labels`) and class attribute (`num_nominal_output_labels`).

Your `Base_CostS` setup could look like this:

```py
Base_CostS= WekaEstimator(classname="weka.classifiers.meta.CostSensitiveClassifier", 
                          options =["-cost-matrix", "[0.0 1.0; 1.0 0.0]", "-S", "1", "-W", "weka.classifiers.trees.ADTree"],
                          nominal_input_vars=[2,3,4],
                          nominal_output_var=True,
                          num_nominal_output_labels=2)
```